# formula Amplitude using FFT

Tags: audio, real-time, signal-processing, fft, amplitude

I want to ask about the formula of amplitude bellow. I am using [Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform). So it returns real and complex numbers. 
after that I must search amplitude for each frequency.

My formula is

```
amplitude = 10 * log (real*real + imagined*imagined)
```

I want to ask about this formula. What is it source? I have been search,  but I don't found any source. Can anybody tell me about that source?

Comment: Normally an 'amplitude' is the length of the 2D vector (a complex number). So it should be sqrt(re^2 + im^2).

Comment: It is indeed. See my answer below - the sqrt cancels out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a combination of two equations:

1: Finding the [magnitude of a complex number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) (the result of an FFT at a particular bin)  - the equation for which is 
m = `sqrt(r^2 + i ^2)`

2: [Calculating relative power in decibels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) from an amplitude value - the equation for which is `p =10 * log10(A^2/Aref^2) == 20 log10(A/Aref)` where `Aref` is a some reference value.

By inserting `m` from equation 1 into `a` from equation 2 with `ARef = 1` we get:

`p = 10 log(r^2 + i ^ 2)`

Note that this gives you a measure of relative signal *power* rather than amplitude.

Comment: thx for answer my question. I understand now. do you know Root Mean Square Amplitude?

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the formula likely comes from the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Power_quantities) of Decibel, with the reference P0 set to 1, assuming with `log` you meant a logarithm with base 10.

The second part, i.e. the `P1=real^2 + imagined^2` in the link above, is the square of the modulus of the Fourier coefficient `cn` at the `n-`th frequency you are considering.

A Fourier coefficient is in general a complex number (See its definition in the case of a DFT [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition)), and `P1` is by definition the square of its modulus.  The FFT that you mention is just one way of calculating the DFT. In your case, likely the real and complex numbers you refer to are actually the real and imaginary parts of this coefficient `cn`.

- `sqrt(P1)` is the modulus of the Fourier **coefficient** `cn` of the signal at the `n-`th frequency.
- `sqrt(P1)/N`, is the amplitude of the Fourier **component** of the signal at the `n-`th frequency (i.e. the amplitude of the harmonic component of the signal at that frequency), with `N` being the number of samples in your signal. To convince yourself you need to divide by `N`, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#equation_Eq.2) equation. However, the division factor depends on the definition/convention of Fourier transform that you use, see the note just above [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Properties), and the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58163/dft-why-are-the-definitions-for-inverse-and-forward-commonly-switched).

Comment: thx for answer. i am little bit confuse. i am using JTransform. it using split radix and mixed radix. so am i need to divide by N?

Comment: Yes you are. and the Root Mean Square Amplitude is `sqrt(P1)/N=sqrt(real^2 + imagined^2)/N` for a certain frequency.